# "Unable to create media player" and "setDataSource Failed" error. mediaplayer is not getting created when using URI for data source

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play sound when my CountDownTimer is finished, but when I try to set data source for media player it throws an exception, I'm setting the data source using URI, and I'm getting that URI from DataStore

The following is the code for getting the URI:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        changeSettings()
        totalTimeForTimer = if (dataStore.getFocusLengthFromDataStore() != null) {
            totalTimeForPomo * 60 * 1000
        } else {
            25 * 60 * 1000
        }
        URI = dataStore.getSoundUri().toUri()
    }
```

this above code is running in the oncreate of main activity.

The following code is of onFinish() of the CountDownTimer:

```
override fun onFinish() {
            var mp = MediaPlayer()
            try {
                if (URI != null) mp.setDataSource(this@MainActivity, URI!!) //line 171
                else Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "null uri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mp.prepareAsync()
                mp.setOnPreparedListener { mp.start() }
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

when this above code runs I get the following error in logcat:

```
2023-06-02 09:21:46.275 28750-28750 MediaPlayerNative  com.hemant.pomoapp  E  Unable to create media player
2023-06-02 09:21:46.276 28750-28750 AndroidRuntime     com.hemant.pomoapp  D  Shutting down VM
2023-06-02 09:21:46.286 28750-28750 AndroidRuntime     com.hemant.pomoapp  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hemant.pomoapp, PID: 28750
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:641)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978) 
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1205)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1192)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1109)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1018)
    at com.hemant.pomoapp.MainActivity$startClock$1.onFinish(MainActivity.kt:171)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8068)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978) 
2023-06-02 09:21:46.349 28750-28750 Process  com.hemant.pomoapp  I  Sending signal. PID: 28750 SIG: 9
```

The errors mainly are "Unable to create media player" and "setDataSource Failed"

The line 171 is indicated above in code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225687/android-unable-to-create-mediaplayer check the answer here